# Is it correct to put "{site_url}" inside a global variable?

Tags: global-variables

As the title says, is it correct? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables declared in Design > Templates > Global Variables cannot contain EE tags, PHP, or other variables inside them.

> User-defined global variables are not run through the template engine,
>   so you cannot place EE Tags, PHP, or variables inside them.

If you need to place EE tags inside re-usable bits of code then you'll need to use Snippets: Design > Templates > Snippets. They're parsed at a very early stage of template rendering so can contain dynamic variables.